# pgr_dijkstra select shortest path for pairs

Tags: pgrouting, postgis-2.0, dijkstra

I have a a set of start and end nodes in a table

best_routes

```
start_vid | end_vid 
-------------------
1        |   7
2         |   8
3         |   9
```

I want to use pgr_dijkstra to create shortest paths for the group of pairs of source and targets, many-to-many creates too much redundant data so essentially I want one-one-one paths for the whole set of pairs

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra(
    'SELECT id, start_vid as source, end_vid as target, mincost, reverse_cost FROM edge_table',
    best_routes.start_vid, best_routes.end_vid
```

been stuck for hours please help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for has been added to pgRouting recently and is available under the name "Combinations", for example the Dijkstra implementation: https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_dijkstra.html#combinations

You should use the latest pgRouting release V3.2.